# Supressing Warning statements in SAS

Tags: sas

Are there any system options available that'll suppress warning messages?

Our license ends in 45 days, so any data or proc step we use, a 4 line warning message appears, greatly increasing our log output (one of our logs ended up being 70MB and couldn't even be viewed in dos!). Anyone know of an option or fix for this? Renewing the license isn't in my hands.

Comment: Contact your SAS representatives. They should be able to reset a parameter that controls that message. Otherwise, they will tell you where to send the renewal payment :)

Answer (score 1):

I was at a SAS conference yesterday, there is no 'easy' way of disabling the warning. Even options nowarn does not work.

Alternatively, have you considered putting 'options nonotes' (as suggested above) in certain sections of your code where you do not need a log output? I can appreciate that this isn't always possible.

Have you tried changing your PCs date and time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any easy way to turn off all warning messages, or these ones specifically, other than changing the system date and time, as suggested by @lx_online.

Other possible workarounds:

- Switch to a more robust text editor for viewing your log files, e.g. notepad++
- Use other log-related options to reduce the size of your log output, e.g. `nosource`, `nomprint`
- Disable logging altogether (via `proc printto`) for sections of code where you don't require log output

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `options nonotes`?

Comment: Notes are not warnings. "options nonotes" only removes notes.